# SSD crash after failed windows restore

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, ssd, windows-7-restore

I am going to explain my situation completely. I was upgrading windows 7 to 10 (genuine) on my laptop. The upgrade did not go well. Windows tried to restore itself to a former status and there the problem occurred.

The restore failed too. and ever since then i cant detect my SSD completely. I tried to make a fresh install of windows.

windows installer does not identify the disk at all. After searching a bit over the internet i found a way to diskpart from this screen and the disk is shown as 22gb.

at first i was unsure. so i unplugged the SSD and attached to my desktop computer to see if its ok. The desktop itself could not identify the SSD properly. It asked for a format first hand. I did the format and the capacity was 22gb of the drive.

The SSD is new and I am very upset about this. Is this a hardware issue or can i fix this by some partition tool?

These are the tools tried-

```
Windows installer tools.
Windows installer cmd diskpart
Ubuntu live gparted

Windows partition manager (on another working pc)
```

Comment: This doesn't sound normal. What was that way that made it show up as a 22 GB drive?

Comment: I added all the tools i used to view my hard disk. windows installer, diskpart, partition manager, ubuntu gparted etc..

Comment: Please someone tell me the SSD is not lost

Comment: I was able to install a fresh windows 7 back on the SSD. but disk size is still showing as 22gb. Its not usable

Comment: Have you tried checking the partition manager of windows ?
Add some screenshots if you can. I am talking about this screen: [windows partitions](http://i.stack.imgur.com/X1aRm.png)